# How to prevent drush migrate:import from updating existing content?

Tags: drush, migrations, importing-exporting

Drush migrate:import (version 10.3.6) seems to be updating existing content regardless if the --update option is used or not. What could be the problem?
I've tested it both with and without the --update option and it behaves the same way. However, when I ran it using the migration tools module, it is opposite - nothing gets updated in both cases..
It seems this problem has started after the site in question was upgraded to d9 from d8. Currently I have no idea where to look and would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Migration _always_ updates the target entity if the source fields have changed, the `--update` option is only used to _force_ an update even if the source has not changed.

Comment: @Hudri That would require the source to be changing all the time which isn't the case. It updates the existing content on each migration, without the --update option.